# How to create the layout to full fill all the screen of android device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Can any one explain me to how to create the layout to full fill all the screen of android device without create individual layout for all screen of android device.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: in xml: android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" Or did I missunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use programmatically you can use in this way.
The "LinearLayout" can be replaced by any Container View.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
        l.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        setContentView(l);
}
```